# Send flash messages like notifications without reloading page

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to implement flash messages on a page in such a way, that they act like status updates to something a user has submitted on that page. In detail, there is a form on that page and once the user pressed submit, it is posted to a route which handles processing, which however takes some time.
During that processing, I would like to give status updates on the very same page, ideally without reloading the page all the time.

As an extreme example, how could something like this work:

```
app.get('/index', function(req,res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        //send a flash every 2 seconds
        setTimeout(function(i) {
            req.flash('This is ' + i);
        }, 2 * 1000 * i, i);
    };
    res.render('../views/index.ejs');
})
```

Is this possible? I had a look at 'express-flash-notification', for which I am unsure though if it can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally flash notifications add a bit of extra information when you're templating a new page. Libraries such as `express-flash-notification` won't be much use if you'd rather not reload the page.

The common approach for this scenario is to make a HTTP call in the browser using JavaScript and dynamically update the DOM with with the returned information. You might choose to use something like AJAX (found in jQuery) for this.

The general flow would be this, but you'd tailor it for your specific needs.

1. Send up the form using an AJAX call from frontend JS, (perhaps you're processing an image or something).
2. The server sends back a 200 OK response to indicate the upload was successful.
3. The frontend then makes a HTTP request every few seconds to the server to ask for a status update. This is returned as json (`res.json({})`). The frontend JS then displays this as needed.

You may choose to use something like web sockets for this status update as well, but if this is your first time approaching frontend AJAX calls then I'd suggest polling (making a request once every few seconds) for now.